# How to display images from an array in vuepress or vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuepress

I have an array which looks like below:

```
  questions: [
    {
      question: "How do you say 'My Car' in Malayalam",
      answers: {
        a: "a) Ente Car",
        b: "b) Ninte/Ningalude Car",
        c: "c) Onte Car",
        d: "d) Aarudeyo Car",
      },
      images: "@alias/vallamkali.jpg",
      correctAnswer: "a",
    },
    {
      question: "How do you say 'your Car' in Malayalam",
      answers: {
        a: "a) Onte Car",
        b: "b) Aarudeyo Car",
        c: "c) Ninte/Ningalude Car",
        d: "d) Ente Car",
      },
      images: "@alias/il_leki.png",
      correctAnswer: "c",
    },
    {
      question: "How do you say 'our car' in Malayalam",
      answers: {
        a: "a) Achante Car",
        b: "b) Ninte/Ningalude Car",
        c: "c) Ente Car",
        d: "d) Nammalude/Njangalude Car",
      },
      images: "@alias/isthapetta_doubt.jpg",
      correctAnswer: "d",
    },
  ],
```

but when I try to print using the below code

```
        <div v-if="index < count">
          <p>{{ questions[index]['question']}}</p>
          <p>{{ questions[index]['images']}}</p
        </div>
```

Only the questions are generated correctly but the images are not displayed properly, only the location gets printed as below and is highlighted in blue. Please help.

[image: Image not displayed only address]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use the function call.
I directly used `require` keyword in the `img` tag itself and it worked.

```
<img :src="require(`@alias/${questions[index]['images']}`)" alt="No image here too" />
```

@Nikola Pavicevic - Thanks for helping me think in this direction!

Answer (score 2):

You can not display images in p tag
You need to make method or computed property (assuming images = il_leki.png):

```
methods: {
  getImg(img) {
    return require(`@alias/${img}`);
  }
}
```

then in template call that method in img tag (instead p tag) passing img :

```
<img :src="getImg(questions[index]['images']) />
```

Comment: `aliased with mapping '@alias': '/home/robo/git/vuepress-easymalayalam/imgs' to '/home/robo/git/vuepress-easymalayalam/imgs/${img}'`

I am getting the following error when trying to build using `vuepress build`. Build fails.

Somehow the alias is not being converted here properly.

I have set the image path correctly -> `images: il_leki.png`